# Elisp ido mode with history for a list fo symbols

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, history, ido

I have a finite list of symbols and I want to make an ido based user interface to select among them, but i also want this to be able to remember. What I came up with is this:

```
(defvar hist nil)
(ido-completing-read "What, ... is your favorite color? " '("red" "green" "blue") nil t nil 'hist)
```

But no matter how many times i choose green the colors seem to come up in the same order and hist remains nil.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elisp uses dynamic scoping, which means that variable names really matter.  More specifically, in your case you have a naming conflict between your `hist` and the `hist` variable used by ido.  Always use a `<prefix>-` thingy on global variables to avoid such problems.

Comment: I tried `my-hist` instead of `hist` and It actually changes the `my-hist` variable and behaves right when I do M-p. But the results are still in the original order.

Comment: Maybe it was not meant to change the sequence of the options. I think it works as it was supposed to now. Thank you